# Multiple validations in FineUploader

Tags: reactjs, fine-uploader

I'm using `FineUploader` in my React app to upload files to Azure Blob Storage. I'm currently using validation to make sure a user can only upload one file. I now want to add two more validations:

1. I want to allow only `JPG` and `PNG` files
2. I also want to make sure that the pixel size of the file user can upload must be at least 300x300 pixels. In other words, I want to impose both width and height requirements

How do I add these validations? Do I need a validation property inside `options` for each requirement or do they go into the existing one? My current validation looks like this:

```
// Omitted for brevity
constructor(props) {

   super(props);
   this.uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
            options: {
                cors: {
                    expected: true,
                    sendCredentials: false
                },
                signature: {
                    endpoint: "some-url.com"
                },
                request: {
                    endpoint: "my-container-url"
                },
                validation: {
                    multiple: false
                }
            },
            callbacks: {
                onError: function (id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {

                }
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume react/fine-uploader don't change it, by [Documentation](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options.html#validation), you should do it like this.

```
options: {
  multiple: false,
  cors: {
    expected: true,
    sendCredentials: false
  },
  signature: {
    endpoint: "some-url.com"
  },
  request: {
    endpoint: "my-container-url"
  },
  validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
    image:{
      minHeight: 300,
      minWidth: 300
    }
  }
}
```

PS. I didn't use fineuploader in react, so please see if this is working as well in react.

---

**Answer to update**

In case you want to have your own validation, first of all you should not use `onError`.
`onError` is invoked if and only if `error` occurs. You validate the image size, though the image doesn't match your criteria, it is NOT `error`.

Then you have two choice to do your validation, that depends on what effect you want. First you need to know the flow of events. It is:

> `onSubmit` -> validation -> `onValidate`

The work (check is image or not) you most likely want can be done on both three places.

If you want it in the validation, then the answer I provided already made it (`allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']`). But let's say you want to make some customization of alert or other checking, you need to do it in `onValidate`.

```
callbacks:{
  onValidate: function(data, button_container) {
    console.log(data); //data.name && data.size
    return false;
  }
}
```

But please be reminded that in `onValidate`, you can only get back file name and file size, no other information.

If you want to also check the width & height, you probably need to take a look on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179835/how-to-get-dimensions-of-the-image-in-fine-uploader-before-submitted-to-server-a) (give OP a upvote if you find this is what you want.)

Comment: @Zeromus, I think multiple should be outside, it is core arg for fineuploader

Comment: The min and max requirements for the image are not working. I did it exactly the way you suggested here i.e. in an `image` object but it didn't work. I also tried `image.minHeight` and `image.minWidth` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Sam, may I know your fineuploader and fineuploader-wrapper version, not react-fineuploader

Comment: @MatrixTai `FineUploader` is `5.14.2` and `fine-uploader-wrappers` is `1.0.0`

Comment: @MatrixTai Do you think the suggested solution is not working due to a version conflict?

Comment: @Sam, no, I tested, all works smoothly while not in react. I read the source code of `fine-uploader-wrappers`, it just copy all options to a normal fineuploader, so that's make me no idea why it does not work in your case. You may try to update `fine-uploader-wrappers` to `1.0.1` as it fix a returning `Promise` problem which may related.

Comment: @MatrixTai Updating `fine-uploader-wrappers` to `1.0.1` did the trick. Thank you! One follow up question if I may: I want to give the user some type of indication e.g. alert, etc. if `minWidth` or `minHeight` are below requirements. I implemented `onValidate()` function, as described in documentation but I'm not hitting my `debugger` point that I placed inside the function when I try to upload a file smaller than requirements. Any idea what may be causing the issue? Here's the link to documentation: https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#validate

Comment: @Sam, How do you set the onValidate()? May I have the code?

Comment: @MatrixTai Please see the `UPDATE` I added to the original post. In the initialization of fineUploader, there's a `callbacks` section and under `onError`, I was expecting to hit my `debugger` point but it never does.

Comment: @Sam, um, I updated a week ago, is the updated version solve your problem?